# Counting duplicate values in a multidimensional array and populating values based on that

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count, duplicates

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 90
        [event_date] => 2012-11-29
        [multi] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 86
        [event_date] => 2012-11-29
        [multi] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 52
        [event_date] => 2012-11-30
        [multi] => 0
    )

)
```

which I am generating on the fly with the following code:

```
        $dates = array();
    $curr_date = array();
    $iteration_date = null;

    foreach ( $query as $q ) {
        $event_id = $q->ID;

        $curr_date['event_id'] = $event_id;
        $curr_date['event_date'] = date('Y-m-d', get_post_meta($event_id, 'event_unix_date', true));


        if ( empty($iteration_date) ) {
            $iteration_date = $curr_date['event_date'];
            $curr_date['multi'] = 1;
        } elseif ( $iteration_date == $curr_date['event_date'] ) {
            $curr_date['multi'] = 1;
        } else {
            $iteration_date = $curr_date['event_date'];
            $curr_date['multi'] = 0;
        }

        array_push($dates, $curr_date);
    }
```

This is based off a MySQL database result.

What I'm attempting to do is: 
Check to see if there are arrays with the same `[event_date]`, if so, count how many, do a special piece of code (a function is fine), and depending on what is output, set the `[multi]` value to 1, 2 or 3 depending on that condition.

Basic logic would be:

Check to see if there are multiple `[event_date]`'s. If there are, check category on all of the matching duplicate dates. If all dates are X, populate `[multi]` with 1, if all dates are Y, populate with 2, if dates are mixed X & Y, populate with 3. If there is only a single date, populate with 1 or 2 depending on which category it is in.

I thought I was on the right track by just looping through the query (it is DESC by event_date), but this won't let me check the individual entries category and populate based on that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you rephrase/provide more detail on the paragraph immediately after your sentence "Basic logic would be:"?  Also, could you provide the snippet of code that you tried, that did not work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we to assume a sorted multidimensional array (by ascending [event_date]) every time?
If so, you could:

```
function multi_counter($big_array, $sorted, $storage){
$multi_count=0; // since by default there are no multiples
$multi_items=array(0); // starting at the beginning of the array
$length = count($big_array); // counting before loop
for($i=0;$i<$length-1;$i++){ // the -1 is so we don't get undefined index on last run
    if($big_array[$i][$sorted]===$big_array[$i+1][$sorted]){ //testing for similarity
        $multi_items[]=$i+1;        // adding the multi found to temp storage
        $multi_count++;             // adding to # of multis
// CALL A FUNCTION HERE SINCE THEY MATCH???
    }else{  
        foreach($multi_items as $key=>$multi){  // if not similar, go back and assign stored multis
            $big_array[$multi][$storage]=$multi_count;  // assigning stored vals
        }
        $multi_count=0; // resetting counter
        $multi_items=array($i+1); // resetting to next item
    }
}
foreach($multi_items as $key=>$multi){  // forcing assign at end of loop
    $big_array[$multi][$storage]=$multi_count; 
}
return $big_array; // returning the newly modified array
```

}

Is that what you were talking about? You can insert a call to another function where I commented one in. Question was unclear, but this is what it sounded like what you wanted.

The function parses the array given as the first parameter, checking if the second parameter is similar in each subarray, and storing them in the subarrays in a key named whatever you put for the third parameter.

Comment: I appreciate this bit of code. Although it wasn't exactly what I needed, I was able to modify it to achieve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the dates in an array.  Then as you loop through your events increment that date by one.  At the end of the loop you will know how many events you have on each date.  you would then need to loop back through and add your multi record though.  You could also just use the date array as a loopup.

```
$dates = new array();

foreach ( $query as $q ) {
  if(array_key_exists($q['event_date'], $dates)
    $dates[$q['event_date']]++;
  else
    $dates[$q['event_date']] = 1;
}
```